# How to call a method inside a class that is connected to redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class FirstClass extends React.Component{
  callMeFromSecondClass(){
    //code to execute
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FirstClass);

class SecondClass extends React.Component{
    render(){
      <div onClick={FirstClass.callMeFromSecondClass}></div>
    }
}
```

How to call the method "callMeFromSecondClass" by clicking on the element?

Comment: This isn't something usually done in react. Methods of a component aren't normally called directly by another. Instead you would pass the method by a prop.